# Grant admin rights in ejabberd

Tags: admin, ejabberd, rights

I want to provide a specific user with admin rights in ejabberd. I've tried to change the ejabberd.cfg file as follows:

```
{access, configure, [{allow, admin},{allow, pierre}]
```

I've restarted the server, and tried to connect with the user account "pierre", although, I couldn't manage the server with the user account. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

If you see example in config file (yaml format), you can just uncomment and adapt the admin ACL. Assuming pierre user is on domain localhost:

```
acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "pierre": "localhost"
```

Note: .cfg format is now legacy. You should use the YAML format which is easier to manage.